# Swift create new arrays based on a single array from a property

Tags: swift

I'm rater new to Swift and I'm stuck in a piece of code where I have to convert a single dimensional array of items,
to a new multidimensional array but grouping the items checking for a similarity of a variable.

Like this:

```
var arr1 = [("polly", 23, uk), ("polly", 19, canada), ("polly", 29, us), ("jenny", 78, ireland), ("jenny", 78, ireland)....]
```

then, grouping all the items by the same name, I wish to have this:

```
arrA = (do some code and return this) [("polly", 23, uk), ("polly", 19, canada), ("polly", 29, us)]
arrB = (do some code and return this) [("jenny", 78, ireland), ("jenny", 78, ireland)]

arrFinal = [arrA, arrB]
```

Basically, I have a list of items to split in each group in a tableview,
each section need to show the items that have the same property, and the user
choose from a menu, which property use (name, age or enumerator) to group
all the items per each section.

Thanks!

Comment: Step one: use structs not tuples.

Comment: Step two: is this real code???? The only way a bare term like `uk` could compile is if you've defined it somewhere. Well, where? How is it defined? Or did you mean the string `"uk"`? Ah, I see it might be an enum. But that is not enum syntax either. Please show _real code_.

Comment: Swift 4.1 introduces "Dictionary grouped by" initialiser. It seems to be the perfect fit for your case. Have a look at this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init

Comment: @matt is not the real code, I only described the problem and find some clean solution for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you do some prep work, this is essentially a one-liner. Here's the prep (my assumptions are a little different from yours):

```
enum Country {
    case uk
    case canada
    case us
    case ireland
}
struct Person {
    let name : String
    let age : Int
    let country : Country
}
let arr = [
    Person(name: "polly", age: 23, country: .uk),
    Person(name: "polly", age: 19, country: .canada),
    Person(name: "polly", age: 29, country: .us),
    Person(name: "jenny", age: 78, country: .ireland),
    Person(name: "jenny", age: 78, country: .ireland),
]
```

And here's the actual code:

```
let arr2 = Array(Dictionary.init(grouping: arr) {$0.name}.values)
```

To group by, say, age instead of name, change `$0.name` to `$0.age`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking! :) re: you are my hero of the day! 